# How can I get the map data frame fill the page layout (ArcObjects java)

Tags: arcobjects, java, arcgis-10.2

I need to export a map for several extents (typically states or regions of a country) to PDF. I have a MXD document that I open in an ArcObject console program.

I manage to set the PageLayout to A2 form and change the orientation of the page depending on my extent.

Nevertheless, I would like to set the data frame to fill my PageLayout with a given margin (1cm for example) between the PageLayout and the data frame, and then change the map extent to my region extent. How can I do that please ?

My actual code is

```
                    IPageLayout pageLayout = (IPageLayout)activeView;
                IPage page = pageLayout.getPage();

                if(regionExtent.getHeight() > regionExtent.getWidth()) {
                    log.info("Orientation : Portrait");
                    page.setOrientation((short) 1);
                } else {
                    log.info("Orientation : Paysage");
                    page.setOrientation((short) 2);
                }
                log.info("Format : A2");
                page.setFormID(esriPageFormID.esriPageFormA2);
                page.setUnits(esriUnits.esriCentimeters);
                page.setStretchGraphicsWithPage(true);
                pageLayout.zoomToWhole();
                pageLayout.setAlignToMargins(true);

                IMap map = activeView.getFocusMap();
                // here I have to get the map fill the pageLayout
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution:
As the PageLayout is a GraphicsContainer, I can access every IElement of it, included the map as an IElement or IMapFrame. Then I change the mapFrame dimensions and align it with my page margins, before zooming the map to the region extent :

```
IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = (IGraphicsContainer)pageLayout;
    graphicsContainer.reset();
    IElement mapElement = null;
    while(!(mapElement instanceof IMapFrame)) {
        mapElement = graphicsContainer.next();
    }

    Envelope mapElementEnvelope = new Envelope();
    mapElementEnvelope.setXMin(margin);
    mapElementEnvelope.setYMin(margin);

    if(extent.getHeight() > extent.getWidth()) {
        log.info("Orientation : Portrait");
        page.setOrientation((short) 1);
        mapElementEnvelope.setXMax(paperWidth - margin);
        mapElementEnvelope.setYMax(paperHeight - margin);
    } else {
        log.info("Orientation : Paysage");
        page.setOrientation((short) 2);
        mapElementEnvelope.setXMax(paperHeight - margin);
        mapElementEnvelope.setYMax(paperWidth - margin);
    }

    mapElement.setGeometry(mapElementEnvelope);

    pageLayout.zoomToWhole();
    pageLayout.setAlignToMargins(true);

    double w = extent.getWidth();
    double h = extent.getHeight();
    extent.expand(expandExtentPercents * w, expandExtentPercents * h, false);
    ((IActiveView)map).setExtent(extent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Filling the map layout with you data extent you could just zoom to the layer.  If there is a certain feature within the layer that defines the extent than you could use a query filter to select that feature than zoom to the selected feature.  A general web search should give you some leads on zooming to layers, setting query filters, or zooming to selected features.

Comment: I can already get the extent of a region and zoom to it with map.setExtent(regionExtent). The problem is that the map don't fill the page layout.

Comment: @superrache, I thought that was part of your question, "then change the map extent to my region extent. How can I do that please"?  You may want to edit your question.